# Nodes and Boundary Conditions in Finite Element Method

Tags: php, object-oriented

The problem:

- A `Node` is located in a specific coordinate (x, y, z).
- A `Node` can be one of these types: `None`, `Hinge`, `Roll`, `Fixed`. (it is called Boundary Condition)
  Different boundary condition type determine a `Node`'s Degree of Freedom.

I have one Abstract `NodeBase` class and multiple classes of nodes inheriting them.  Please check if this is a good approach.

I also have some Abstract Data Types, such as `Coordinate`, `ForceSet`, `DisplacementSet`. They are classes containing only public variables. (want to use them as `struct`s, like in C++)

**NodeBase.php:**

```
abstract class NodeBase {

    /** @var Coordinate */
    protected $coordinate;

    /** @var ForceSet */
    protected $forces;

    /** @var DisplacementSet */
    protected $displacements;

    /** @var int index / ordering of this node in a project */
    protected $idNumber;

    /** @var int static variable, giving each node a unique Id Number */
    private static $idCounter = 0;

    /** @var double $localAngle local rotation of the node */
    protected $localAngle;

    public function __construct(array $params = null)
    {
        // For Generating ID Numbers (starting from 1)
        self::$idCounter++;

        // Initialization
        $this->coordinate = new Coordinate();
        $this->forces = new ForceSet();
        $this->displacements = new DisplacementSet();
        $this->idNumber = self::$idCounter;

        // Assign values with parameter (if exists)
        if (isset($params))
        {
            if (isset($params['x']))
            {
                $this->coordinate->x = $params['x'];
            }
            if (isset($params['y']))
            {
                $this->coordinate->y = $params['y'];
            }
            if (isset($params['angle']))
            {
                $this->localAngle = $params['angle'];
            }
        }
    }

    public function setCoordXY($x, $y)
    {
        $this->coordinate->x = $x;
        $this->coordinate->y = $y;
    }
    public function setCoordXYZ($x, $y, $z)
    {
        $this->coordinate->x = $x;
        $this->coordinate->y = $y;
        $this->coordinate->z = $z;
    }

    public function getX()
    {
        return $this->coordinate->x;
    }

    public function getY()
    {
        return $this->coordinate->y;
    }

    public function getZ()
    {
        return $this->coordinate->z;
    }

    public function getIdNumber()
    {
        return $this->idNumber;
    }

    public function getAngle()
    {
        return $this->localAngle;
    }

    public function setAngle($angle)
    {
        $this->localAngle = $angle;
    }

    public function getAngleMatrix()
    {
        return array(
            array(1, 0),
            array(0, 1),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param String[] $forceNames available values = 'Fx', 'Fy', 'Fz', 'Mx', 'My', 'Mz'
     * @return SimpleEquation[] forces retrieved (array of SimpleEquations)
     */
    public function getForces(array $forceNames)
    {
        $result = array();
        $forcesArray = get_object_vars($this->forces);
        foreach ($forceNames as $fName)
        { /** @var $fName String */
            $result = $forcesArray[$fName];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param String[] $forceNames available values = 'Fx', 'Fy', 'Fz', 'Mx', 'My', 'Mz'
     * @return String[] forces retrieved (array of Strings)
     */
    public function getForcesString(array $forceNames)
    {
        $forces = $this->getForces($forceNames);
        $result = array();
        foreach ($forces as $f)
        { /** @var $f SimpleEquation */
            $result[] = $f->getString();
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param String[] $dispNames available values = 'dx', 'dy', 'dz', 'Ox', 'Oy', 'Oz'
     * @return SimpleEquation[] displacements retrieved (array of SimpleEquations)
     */
    public function getDisplacements(array $dispNames)
    {
        $result = array();
        $dispArray = get_object_vars($this->displacements);
        foreach ($dispNames as $dName)
        { /** @var $dName String */
            $result = $dispArray[$dName];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param String[] $dispNames available values = 'dx', 'dy', 'dz', 'Ox', 'Oy', 'Oz'
     * @return String[] displacements retrieved (array of Strings)
     */
    public function getDisplacementsString(array $dispNames)
    {
        $displacements = $this->getDisplacements($dispNames);
        $result = array();
        foreach ($displacements as $d)
        { /** @var $d SimpleEquation */
            $result[] = $d->getEquation();
        }
        return $result;
    }

    public function addForceValue($forceName, $value)
    {
        $this->getForce($forceName)->addValue($value);
    }

    public function solveForce($forceName, $value)
    {
        $this->getForce($forceName)->solve($value);
    }

    public function solveDisplacementValue($dispName, $value)
    {
        $this->getDisplacement($dispName)->solve($value);
    }

    public function getForce($forceName)
    {
        switch ($forceName)
        {
            case 'Fx':
                return $this->forces->Fx;
            case 'Fy':
                return $this->forces->Fy;
            case 'Fz':
                return $this->forces->Fz;
            case 'Mx':
                return $this->forces->Mx;
            case 'My':
                return $this->forces->My;
            case 'Mz':
                return $this->forces->Mz;
        }
    }

    public function getDisplacement($dispName)
    {
        switch ($dispName)
        {
            case 'dx':
                return $this->displacements->dx;
            case 'dy':
                return $this->displacements->dy;
            case 'dz':
                return $this->displacements->dz;
            case 'Ox':
                return $this->displacements->Ox;
            case 'Oy':
                return $this->displacements->Oy;
            case 'Oz':
                return $this->displacements->Oz;
        }
    }
}
```

**NoneNode.php:**

```
class NoneNode extends NodeBase {

    public function __construct(array $params = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($params);

        $this->forces->Fx = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::KNOWN_VALUE, 'Fx');
        $this->forces->Fy = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::KNOWN_VALUE, 'Fy');
        $this->forces->Mz = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::KNOWN_VALUE, 'Mz');

        $this->displacements->dx = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::UNKNOWN_VALUE, 'dx');
        $this->displacements->dy = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::UNKNOWN_VALUE, 'dy');
        $this->displacements->Oz = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::UNKNOWN_VALUE, 'Oz');
    }

}
```

**HingeNode.php:**

```
class HingeNode extends NodeBase {

    public function __construct(array $params = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($params);

        $this->forces->Fx = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::UNKNOWN_VALUE, 'Fx');
        $this->forces->Fy = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::UNKNOWN_VALUE, 'Fy');
        $this->forces->Mz = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::KNOWN_VALUE, 'Mz');

        $this->displacements->dx = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::KNOWN_VALUE, 'dx');
        $this->displacements->dy = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::KNOWN_VALUE, 'dy');
        $this->displacements->Oz = new SimpleEquation(SimpleEquation::UNKNOWN_VALUE, 'Oz');
    }

}
```

I have two other classes: `FixedNode` and `RollNode` that I don't list them here, because they are very similar to both of `NoneNode` and `HingeNode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all looks good to me, though you can simplify your NodeBase `getForce()` and `getDisplacement()` methods if you use [variable properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), like so:

```
public function getForce($forceName)
{
    if(isset($this->forces->$forceName))
    {
        return $this->forces->$forceName;
    }
}

public function getDisplacement($dispName)
{
    if(isset($this->displacements->$dispName))
    {
        return $this->displacements->$dispName;
    }
}
```

Which will save you a lot of rewriting if you decide to change the names of any of the properties down the line